# Why seeds won't sprout given excess water?

Tags: botany

What would cause a seed to not sprout despite showing signs of germination given excess water? Oxygen, temperature, and light were sufficient for germination and sprouting in seeds of a slightly lesser amount of water.

Comment: What kind of seeds are we talking about here - some have special requirements

Comment: I think the answer to this question is like this.   Some seeds can sprout with this much water - even germinating underwater. The seed could sprout, but why doesn't it?  Some living things actually have adapted highly specialized conditions for growth - why should this be?  I'll try to come back later and put an answer up if this is right, and nobody else does.

Answer (score 5):

You've stated in your question that oxygen was sufficient for germination, but if there's too much water this probably isn't the case. It's likely given excess water seeds will drown- that is they have not got access to sufficient oxygen to continue germination.